# Rewriting this simple function using c++ STL/Boost instead of system() calls?

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, tar

I need to archive the *.cpp files in a specific directory inside a gzipped tarball.  I need this to happen during runtime as a means of documenting precisely what code (e.g., which versions of which source code files) produced a particular set of results from the program.

So, I wrote the following function.  It usually works fine, but it *has* screwed up once or twice in the past.  I can't recall what happened, exactly, but I remember thinking it was due to using `system()` instead of actually doing the file deletion and archival in the c++ program.

```
void saveSourceCode_TarGZ(string destinationFile) {
    system( ("rm -f " + destinationFile).c_str() );
    system( ("rm -f " + destinationFile + ".gz").c_str() );

    system( ("tar -cvf " + destinationFile + " ./*.cpp").c_str() );
    system( ("gzip " + destinationFile).c_str() );
}
```

The first two lines in the above function simply delete already existing file by the same name as the archive I'm trying to create (`destinationFile`), if it exists.  The last two lines, respectively, create a tarball of all the .cpp files in the current working directory and gzip that tarball.

**How could I rewrite this function using the STL or the Boost libraries?**

I'm very inexperienced at using the Boost libraries, and I'm a total ignoramus when it comes to filesystem management in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no functionality in the STL to compress and decompress files (according to some compression scheme).

That said, there's a small library called lz4 ([link](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/)) which should satisfy your needs.
Snippet taken from `lz4.h`:

```
//****************************
// Simple Functions
//****************************

int LZ4_compress        (const char* source, char* dest, int inputSize);
int LZ4_decompress_safe (const char* source, char* dest, int inputSize, int maxOutputSize);
```

There's also built-in gzip functionality if you can use boost::iostreams, namely [boost::iostreams::gzip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html)